# pass post data curl django

Tags: django, curl

I need to send data by POST. There is this example but do not know how to do this in django. Can someone help

Example :

```
curl https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/ -d\
    "email=suporte@lojamodelo.com.br\
    &token=95112EE828D94278BD394E91C4388F20\
    &currency=BRL\
    &itemId1=0001\
    &itemDescription1=Notebook Prata\
    &itemAmount1=24300.00\
    &itemQuantity1=1\
    &itemWeight1=1000\
    &itemId2=0002\
    &itemDescription2=Notebook Rosa\
    &itemAmount2=25600.00\
    &itemQuantity2=2\
    &itemWeight2=750\
    &reference=REF1234\
    &senderName=Jose Comprador\
    &senderAreaCode=11\
    &senderPhone=56273440\
    &senderEmail=comprador@uol.com.br\
    &shippingType=1\
    &shippingAddressStreet=Av. Brig. Faria Lima\
    &shippingAddressNumber=1384\
    &shippingAddressComplement=5o andar\
    &shippingAddressDistrict=Jardim Paulistano\
    &shippingAddressPostalCode=01452002\
    &shippingAddressCity=Sao Paulo\
    &shippingAddressState=SP\
    &shippingAddressCountry=BRA"
```

Comment: One options is to use the rest-client on firefox (plugin) to test POST requests

Comment: ..or use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) for chrome.

Comment: Do you need to send this from within Django? Ifso look at the [python requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module they make it quite easy to make a POST to an external resource. If not, please elaborate on what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the requests library, but a simple POST does not require anything more than what comes built in to python:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
data = urllib.urlencode({"email":"suporte@lojamodelo.com.br","token":...})
req = urllib2.Request("https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/", data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```